# Adding onclick function to dynamically added button in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to add an onclick function call to dynamically added buttons, like so:

```
ubutton.onclick = function() {
                    navigateHere();
                };
```

This line is within the Vue "methods" area. When I run the client, I get this error in the console: "navigateHere()" is not defined

So, the onclick occurs, but Vue cannot detect the other function. navigateHere() is also a Vue "methods" function.

How can I fix this?

I need navigateHere() within the Vue methods, as it uses Vue Router to redirect to another page.

Comment: The layout is export default {methods: {navigateHere(), callerFunction() } }

Comment: You should invoke it with the scope. try this `this.navigateHere()` instead of `navigateHere()`